# Set the value to ID of the element on click event by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to set the menu to active when click on it. This is what I've tried :

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  var select;
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
     $.each(data, function (index, dataOption) {

      var new_li = $("<li class='level1' id='select_list'><a href='javascript:void(0);' id='" + dataOption.ID + "' class ='selectedcategory'>"  + dataOption.Name + "</a>");

      $('a#' + dataOption.ID).click(function () {
        select = "selected";
        $('.level1').attr("id",select);
      });
     });
    });
  });
</script>
```

What I tried to do is to set the id of 'level1' to selected, when I click on that link. But my coding is set all the link to selected, even I click only 1 link.

Could anyone give me the solution please.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Is your click function working at all? if you put an alert in it will it work?

Comment: @mikevoermans : Yes,sure mikevoermans. It works well.

Comment: I think you are creating multiple `id='select_list'`, right? It is illegal to have multiple elements with the same id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because you are calling `.attr()` on all `.level1` element instead of only the one being clicked by its child so,

change

```
$('.level1').attr("id",select);
```

to

```
$(this).parent().attr('id', select);
```

You also need to remove the "selected" id from the other `<li>`'s by

```
$('.level1').removeAttr('id');
```

So the complete code looks like:

```
  $('a#' + dataOption.ID).click(function () {
      $('.level1').removeAttr('id');
      $(this).parent().attr("id", 'selected');
  });
```

One suggestion though, class is usually used in situation like this when you want to have a `selected` type of a list of menu, if you are using class you'd do something like

```
$('a#' + dataOption.ID).click(function () {
    $('.level1').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
}
```

Looks more concise that way, but I'll leave it up to you :)

Comment: The id of <li> not <a> andreas.

Comment: It works andreas, But when I click second list , the first list still have id='selected'. Could you tell me, how can I reset the first link id='select_list', after I click on the other list.